# SQL Reporting Service URL: 404 Not Found. No funciona la url de reporting service

Tags: sql, url, reporting

al iniciar el report server configuration manager y le doy iniciar, cuando accedo al LINK del servicio web url me da un error que es el de la siguiente imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir la imagen del administrador de configuración del report server??

Comment: Alguna sección en específico?

Comment: Veo que estás en una máquina Windows, el Report Server lo tendrás instalado en el IIS, y el servidor web que tienes activo en el puerto 80 es un Apache.

Comment: Desinstalo el apache? Porque lo necesito para un proyecto de JAVA

Comment: O configura otro puerto para el sitio web del IIS, por ejemplo el 81

Comment: Si pongo puerto 81:Error de Reporting Services
Error interno en el servidor de informes. Vea el registro de errores para obtener más detalles. (rsInternalError) Obtener ayuda en pantalla
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: Primero para el servicio del Apache, luego pon en el IIS el puerto 80 otra vez y pruebas

Comment: reporting services funciona diferente de iis  por lo que ambos pueden existir en puerto 80, pero tienes que configurar el Web Service URL y el Web Portal URL